# Is it possible to do multi-line comments with clearcase?

Tags: comments, clearcase, multiline

I'd like to use multi-line comments with a command's option '-c'.

For example:

```
ct ci -c "hello this should be a multiple \n comment!" file.txt
```

I write a program which does auto-commenting, but some comments are too long to read them clearly in just one line.

How would you pass a multi-line comment to the `cleartool checkin` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-cfile` option of the [`cleartool checkin`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_checkin.htm) command.

That means:

Your script should:

- write your comment in a file
- use that file in the `-cfile` option.

(Make sure of your ClearCase version: [there was a bug with that option](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK67068), fixed only in 7.0.0.4+, 7.1.0.3+ and 7.1)